# Copy recursively, completely ignoring matching directories in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two directories:

```
/dir1
  ├── a/
  └── b/

/dir2
  ├── a/
  └── c/
```

and the result I want in `dir1/` is

```
/dir1
  ├── a/
  ├── b/
  └── c/
```

The directory `dir1/a/` should remain *completely untouched*, even if the files in `dir1/a/` are newer or different than those in `dir2/a/`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool like [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/)?

Comment: @kabanus `rsync` would be fine, or  whatever is concise. I know about `cp -n` but the manpage doesn't indicate that matching subdirectories will be protected recursively. It sounds like it only protects _files_ from being clobbered.

Comment: `rsync` has `--exclude` and `--include` flag.

Comment: `find dir2/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ! -path '*/a' -prune -exec sh -c 'cp -Rv -- "$@" dir1/' _ {} +`  only tested on GNU `find` and `cp` but it has more flags/options that you can use/explore.

Comment: Wow I can't believe all the downvotes! Are we not supposed to be asking questions about using the shell here anymore?

Comment: Downvotes mean “this question does not show any research effort”.

Comment: It was, however, carefully articulated. I was looking for a quick copy-pasteable solution. Not finding one on Stackoverflow, I was trying to help the community by creating a topic that others could easily find later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsync` with `--exclude-from` and `find`:

```
rsync --dry-run -avz \
     --exclude-from=<(find dirs/dir1 -type d -printf "/%P\n") \
     dirs/dir2/ dirs/dir1/
```

- `find dirs/dir1 -type d -printf "/%P\n"` - will find all the directories in `dir1`, print their relative path prefixed with a / to anchor them to the root of the transfer (otherwise if, for example, you have a `dir2/c/a` directory won't be transferred)
- `--exclude-from=` - tells rsync to skip files matching the names from input file
- `<(...)` - process substitution, to feed find's output to rsync (you can use a normal pipe here if you don't have bash since `rsync` supports `-` name for `stdin` something like `find dirs/dir1 -type d -printf "/%P\n" |  rsync --dry-run -avz --exclude-from=- dirs/dir2/ dirs/dir1/`)
- if you have filenames with "\n" in them you can use a null terminator ( `find dirs/dir1 -type d -printf "/%P\0" |  rsync --dry-run -avz -0 --exclude-from=- dirs/dir2/ dirs/dir1/`)
- remove `--dry-run` when you are sure only the files you need are transferred

**Some examples**

No exclude:

```
sorin@test ~/test $ rsync --dry-run -avz dirs/dir2/ dirs/dir1
sending incremental file list
./
a/
a/2.txt
a/3.txt
c/
c/4.txt
c/a/
c/a/2.txt

sent 240 bytes  received 43 bytes  566.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Un-anchored exclude:

```
sorin@test ~/test $ rsync --dry-run -avz --exclude-from=<(find dirs/dir1 -type d -printf "%P\n") dirs/dir2/ dirs/dir1/
sending incremental file list
./
c/
c/4.txt

sent 112 bytes  received 26 bytes  276.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Anchored exclude:

```
sorin@test ~/test $ rsync --dry-run -avz --exclude-from=<(find dirs/dir1 -type d -printf "/%P\n") dirs/dir2/ dirs/dir1/
sending incremental file list
./
c/
c/4.txt
c/a/
c/a/2.txt

sent 165 bytes  received 33 bytes  396.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
sorin@test ~/test $
```